# gulp-useref "additionalStreams" not merging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp-useref

So I have a simple use case, and it seems very similar to the usecase described in the readme for https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref.

I'm trying to generate a templates.js file with all of the Angular templates during the build.  I am trying to do this and NOT have a templates.js file in my local project.  So the idea was to merge the output of the template stream into the useref stream so that the resulting `scripts.js` file would contain all of the files indicated in my index file AND the generated `templates` ouput.

Here's what I have in the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('usemin:dist', ['clean:dist'], function() {
  var templatesStream = gulp.src([
    './app/**/*.html',
    '!./app/index.html',
    '!./app/404.html'
  ]).pipe(templateCache({
    module: 'myCoolApp'
  }));

  var assets = $useref.assets({
    additionalStreams: [templatesStream]
  });

  return gulp.src('./app/index.html')
      .pipe(assets)
      .pipe(assets.restore())
      .pipe($useref())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Now this should allow me to merge the output of the templatesStream and turn it all into one `scripts.js` file, I think...

I've also tried having `<script src="scripts/templates.js"></script>` of many forms sitting in my index file to try and assist it.  None seem to work.

Anyone else doing this same type of thing?  Seems like a common use-case.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by looking closely at the test cases.
I now have a `templates.js` script tag on my `index.html` file which will 404 while in my local environment.

My gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('useref:dist', ['clean:dist'], function() {
  var templateStream = gulp.src([
    './app/**/*.html',
    '!./app/index.html',
    '!./app/404.html'
  ]).pipe(templateCache({
    module: 'digitalWorkspaceApp'
  }));

  var assets = $useref.assets({
    additionalStreams: [templateStream]
  });
  var jsFilter = $filter('**/*.js', {restore: true});

  return gulp.src('./app/index.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe($useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Immediately I can't really see the difference, but it may have all hinged on the addition of this non-existent file in my index.html.